# Determine if function was called without setting global variable

Tags: c++, c++11

What is a good technique to determine if a function was called in C++ without setting a global variable?

```
#include <iostream>

bool var = false;

void X ()
{
    if (var) {std::cout<<" Y called "<< std::endl;}
}

void Y ()
{var = true;}

int main()
{
Y();
X();
}
```

I would really like an example of a way to do this without setting a global variable.

Comment: Well, make your `X`, `Y` and `var` in a class.

Comment: You could make the method the member of a struct or class and set a member variable rather than a global. Or use a static variable within the function.

Comment: Another way would be to pass a callback to the function that you want to know if it has been called.

Comment: If the function has some results, we could check those results. If the function doesn't do anything at all - `void f() { }` - how do we know if it does its nothing? And why do we care? Sounds like [If a tree falls in a forest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_a_tree_falls_in_a_forest).

Comment: Can you explain WHY `X()` needs to be able to test if `Y()` has been called?

Answer (score 2):

If `Y` and `X` are related in this way, then you could move them to a `class`:

```
struct Foo
{
    void X()
    {
         if (var) {std::cout<<" Y called "<< std::endl;}
    }
    void Y()
    {
        var = true;
    }
    Foo() : var(false) /*this is the constructor*/
    {
    }
private:
    bool var;      
};
```

You could even make the members `static`, if you didn't want to have to bother with an *instance* of `Foo`.

Note also the use of a *constructor*. Perhaps you could put your initialisation stuff in there; then you wouldn't need to check the initialisation state in `X`.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way is with a static local variable:

```
void X() {
    static bool done = false;
    // whatever
    done = true;
}
```

The static variable is initialized the first time that the function runs. On subsequent calls it has whatever value was last assigned to it.